# Controllable random numbers of an array

Tags: xcode, random, nsmutablearray

I have 10 numbers (with NSMutableArray) which randomly showed in 10 different labels. But I need to know which number goes to which label. These are answer labels and I should check them with the question if they are the right answer or not. But I should know which answer is where at every time. How can I do that?

Could anyone can help please??

```
for (int y=1; y<11; y++) {

NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cevapLabel%d", y];  
UILabel *label = [self valueForKey:name];

if (number ==1) {
    labelQ.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ix1=", [[arr objectAtIndex:(random()%9)+1] intValue]];

    myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];

    srandom(time(NULL));
    NSUInteger count1 = [myMutableArray count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count1; ++i) {
        int nElements = count1 - i;
        int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
        [myMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex: i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }
```

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:y-1] intValue]];
    }
}

and it goes on for 10 other probabilities

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using?  Who holds the randomness the array, or the generated location / label for which the array's element ultimately goes?

Comment: for (int y=1; y<11; y++) { if{number==1){myMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10", nil];
  srandom(time(NULL));
     NSUInteger count1 = [myMutableArray count];
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count1; ++i) {
                int nElements = count1 - i;
                int n = (random() % nElements) + i;
                [myMutableArray exchangeObjectAtIndex: i withObjectAtIndex:n];
            }label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", [[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:y-1] intValue]];} if(number==2).. and goes on.

Comment: Can you structure that in your question, not in the comment section?

Answer (score 1):

Both NSView and UIView object (as I cant tell from you question whether you are writing for OS X or for iPhone / iPad) have a tag property.

You could simply when applying the data behind NSMutableArray element[n] to the text of the label, apply the "n" value to the tag of the label!!!

Example:

```
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:n]];
myLabel.tag  = n;
```

Comment: @trojanfoe - True, but maybe it doesnt matter so long as the label to hold the element for array index 0 is indeed holding array element index 0. But good point!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for that, tags can work but for the label's text I'm using the for loop and it's like:[[myMutableArray objectAtIndex:y-1] intValue]]. So I can't say the exact number of the objectAtIndex. Maybe I need to tag array's elements. but how?